# Есть ли ссылка в тексте. (PHP)

Tags: search, php

Имеется некий текст, нужной найти там ссылку. Примеров по его замене, удалению в интернете куча. Но мне нужно просто нужно узнать, есть ли хоть одна ссылка в тексте. Если есть, то.. это я уже сам)

Answer (score 1):

Ну если есть "куча примеров" по замене, то перед тем как заменить, обычно "пример" находит то, что надо заменять. Ну так берите пример, и после той строчки, что находит, обрывайте :-)

Если в примерах preg_replace, то копайте в сторону preg_match - с помощью этой функции (и не только этой) можно достичь той цели, которую преследуете.